# for var in key loop displaying the same property instead of 4 different ones

Tags: javascript, for-loop, key, addressbook

Im trying to make an addressbook in javascript and the issue I have is that the properties of my objects are not giving me the info I need. I want 4 different property and not 4 loops of same property.

The for loop is makes a loop of 4 `li`s list items thats gonna be inserted from the info I have in the objects.

But instead I got EMAIL all the loops.

Hope you understand and can help me.
Here is the code.

```
    //Contactlist funktion
function Contact(fname, lname, address, email) { 
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.address = address;
    this.email = email;    
}

// Contacts
var tony = new Contact("Tony", "Stark", "Avengers 123", "i.am.ironman@hotmail.com");
var steve = new Contact("Steve", "Rogers", "Avengers 12", "cap.america@hotmail.com");

//All contacts
var contacts = [tony, steve];

// Appending the objects
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
body.appendChild(ul);

function theContacts() {
var li = document.createElement('li');

    li.innerHTML = tony.fname + ' ' + stark.lname;
    ul.appendChild(li);
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        li = document.createElement('li');

    for (var key in tony) {
        li.innerHTML = key;
    }
        ul.appendChild(li);

    }
}

// Calling the object
theContacts();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Perhaps because you loop on abraham.address ? What if you loop on abraham ?

Comment: I found abraham defined in the bible but not in your code.

Comment: With .address i got the number 11 in all the li's. 
If i put only the objectname (in this case abraham) i got only email.

Comment: Sorry! I have edited to code so the right code is now available! @Superdrac Thanks!

Comment: You want function `theContacts()` output a list of all contacts or only a specific one ?

Comment: I want it to output all contacts with their properties. After i fix this issue I am gonna create a function that takes the info from a form with these property so when someone wants to Add a contact I got that value and appendChild it to this. I dont know if I explained right? @MartinErnst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will output all contacts with their properties as nested unordered lists. I have given classnames to the elements for easy styling. Start just below your `var contacts`.

```
function theContacts() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        outerUL = document.createElement('ul'),
        length = contacts.length;
    outerUL.className = 'contactlist';
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var cont = contacts[i],
            li = document.createElement('li'),
            ul = document.createElement('ul');
        li.className = 'contact'; li.innerHTML = cont.fname + ' ' + cont.lname;
        ul.className = 'infos';
        for (var key in cont) {
            var info = document.createElement('li');
            info.className = key;
            info.innerHTML = cont[key];
            ul.appendChild(info);
        }
        li.appendChild(ul); outerUL.appendChild(li);
    }
    body.appendChild(outerUL);
}
```

The problem you had results from confusion with `var li` inside `theContacts()`.

Comment: OMG! Thanks Martin! You have solved that issue I have and now im gonna go-on to next part of the project! 

I might need some help but i would post it here in stack overflow. Thanks again! :)